# html divide page into two column and overflow content from first column to second one

Tags: html, css, division, css-tables

I want a DIV to be split into two column like a book, and I want to overflow content from first column in to second column

For example: `1234567890abcd` would read as

```
  ---------
  |1 2|90 |
  |3 4|ab |
  |5 6|cd |
  |7_8|___|
```

**Edit:**

HTML engine I am using doesn't understand

```
.two-col{
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

this CSS, I am using this to render HTML http://wkhtmltopdf.org

Comment: please try css3 multicolumn [http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Comment: can it be done without using this set of CSS, the HTML engine I am using isn't understanding this CSS

Answer (score 4):

You can use css3 property `column-count` and acheive the same.

**CSS**

```
.test {
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
column-count: 3;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLyzyb6x/)

Comment: can it be done without using this set of CSS, the HTML engine I am using isn't understanding this CSS

Comment: If I understand @user3833308, they are having the same issue I currently have, essentially with wkhtmltopdf, if you have long columns, they run onto a second page, when the desired behavior is that it would start a 'new set' of columns. So page 1 left column is <li> 1-10, right is 11-20, page 2 left column is 20-30, right column is 30-40

Answer (score 2):

You can [use CSS3 multi-column layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts).

```css
.two-col{
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<p class="two-col">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
```

You can also change the width of columns with `column-width` attribute.

Comment: can it be done without using this set of CSS, the HTML engine I am using isn't understanding this CSS

Comment: What engine are you using? The other way would be to properly cut your text string in 2 parts, and print each part in a separate div side by side.

Comment: Ok so it seems that wkhtmltopdf doesn't support it. But you can tweak it to  create columns anyway. Look at this example : https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1872